# Knockout binding checkbox group with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the following knockoutjs code with 3 checkboxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/gzfff/2/

The issue here is that the checkboxes are not being binded correctly with the json data.

Any clue?

HTML

```
<form>
    <div>
        <div>
            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: properties" value="1" />Property ABC</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: properties" value="2" />Property CON</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: properties" value="3" />Property ZZZ</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<hr/>

<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(properties)"></div>​
```

JS

```
var jsonData= [1,2];

var App = function (jsondata) {
    var self = this;

    self.properties = ko.observableArray(jsondata);
};
var appViewModel = new App(jsonData);
ko.applyBindings(appViewModel);​
```

Thanks

Comment: I have no clue whatsoever.  I am clueless.  Seriously, could you put a little more effort into your question before it gets closed and deleted?

Comment: Also, the Fiddle is nice, but we need the code in your question also.

Comment: Sure, let me put that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
var jsonData= [1,2];
```

to

```
var jsonData= ["1","2"];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hE92D/

Comment: Im using: var jsonData = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(this.Model.IntList)));
The IntList is a List<int>

Comment: But, as you can see from the Fiddle, the checkboxes return strings, not numbers.  So you're going to need some sort of conversion between the strings and the numbers.